# Webpack: SCSS to CSS file

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, sass

How do I take my SCSS source and compile it into a (bonus: minified) CSS file?

One thing that reading to documentation and searching the web makes clear is that everyone seems to be cooking their own soup, there's no standard/recommended way for such a common task.

Comment: This is the million dollar question. If you find any standard way please tell me something, 'cause my soup is getting cold... ;-)

Comment: Do you have an webpack config to use as a base?  I can post what I use, but out of context it might be a bit confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below a minimal example that worked for me:

**package.json:**

```js
{
  …
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.40.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  …
  module: {
    rules: [
      { // CSS assets remaining in the pipeline (e.g. frameworks)
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // or e.g. "vue-style-loader" etc. (optional)
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader"
        ]
      },
      { // SCSS
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader" // (optional)
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  // Plugins
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "./css/my-style.css" // relative to `output.path` by default
    }),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin() // construction suffices, no additional calls needed
  ]
};
```

The `node-sass` module already outputs minified CSS, so if you *know* you won't encounter any raw CSS in your project, you can get rid of the `OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)

First I will transform my scss to css file using this setting in webpack

```
module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Then I'm using webpack-shell-plugin to run postcss command to minify css file. (Bonus I'm also add gzip using Compression plugin to transform css to gzip)

```
plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin({
            test: /\.(js|css)/
        }),
        new WebpackShellPlugin({
            onBuildStart: ['echo "Starting postcss command"'],
            onBuildEnd: ['postcss --dir wwwroot/dist wwwroot/dist/*.css']
        })
    ],
```

Comment: Your config seems OK, you just need to add the MiniCssExtractPlugin to the list of plugins, and configure it there if needed: cf https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#root

Comment: As a personal note, I found the official webpack doc pretty clear and it has lots of example of configs

Comment: @giuseppedeponte The webpack doc for the plugin doesn't even list defaults! And above example isn't valid, as there's no "minimize" flag for css-loader: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#options

That's what I meant when I wrote "everyone is cooking their own soup" -- I cannot get an official answer by the developers as they're in over their heads. Looking at the issue tracker of this particular plugin (I read the discourse in them) doesn't inspire confidence either: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues

Comment: @Tony Ngo Thanks for the example, I'll see where that takes me and report back!